# Yahoo overrides CSS and inline styling of text

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am designing a newsletter that currently looks fine in all email clients except Yahoo. I have tried inline styling and CSS in the style tag and in both concurrently. Nothing I do forces yahoo to respect my font/text styling. Everything defaults to cambria and serif instead of the arial, sansserif I want to display. Does anyone know of a workaround? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [`!important`](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)?

Comment: post some code so we can see where your styling is applied

Answer (score 0):

Post some code so we can help you find a solution.

No clue if this is your issue but I'll post it anyway. Yahoo! Mail will render media queries intended for mobile only. If this is your problem, here is your solution:

**Replace**

```
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #mobileWrapper {width:100% !important}
    .headerText {font-size:24px !important}
  }
</style>
```

**With**

```
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    *[id=mobileWrapper] {width:100% !important}
    *[class=headerText] {font-size:24px !important}
  }
</style>
```

Notice the use of [id or class here] rather than your traditional .class or #id. This will force Yahoo! Mail to render your CSS correctly. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

add `!important;` to the end of your font declaration.